# Does this series converge? Alternating series and ratio tests do not work

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Does the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+2}.$$ converge?

The conditions for the Leibniz alternating series test are not satisfied, as $\frac{n}{n+2}\nrightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Also, the ratio test yields an answer of $R=1$ so is inconclusive. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Hint. You already noted that the  general term does not have limit $0$. Think a bit before you start on tests.

Comment: Alongside the HINT left by Ethan, note that $\frac{n}{n+2}=1-\frac{2}{n+2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that series does not converge, as the sequence $$x_n = (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+2}$$ does not converge to $0$. It does not even converge. Probably, the most simple way to see this is to consider the subsequences
$$a_n:=x_{2n} = \frac{2n}{2n+2}$$
and
$$b_n:=x_{2n+1} = -\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}.$$
Obviously, $a_n\to 1$ and $b_n\to-1$ as $n\to\infty$, hence $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n\neq\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n.$$